# Union of set differences equals...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I was presented with thefollowing question

> Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be sets. Which of the following claims hold true (in general)?
>
> 1. $A \cap B \subseteq A \cup B$
> 2. $A \setminus B = B \setminus A$
> 3. $A\cup (B\cap C) = (A \cup B) \cap C$
> 4. $A\cup (B\cap C) = (A \cap B) \cup (A\cap C)$
> 5. $(A \setminus B)\cup (A\setminus C) = A \setminus (B \cup C)$

I'm certain that 1 and 4 are true and that 2 and 3 are not true. However, what about 5? I attempted the following proof.

#### Proof

''$\subseteq$''

Let $x \in ( A \setminus B ) \cup (A \setminus C)$. Then $x \in A \setminus B$ or $A \setminus C$. If $x \in A \setminus B$, then $x \in A$, but $x \notin B$. Then $x \in A \setminus B \cup C$. An identical argument holds if $x \in A \setminus C$.

''$\supseteq$''

Let $x \in A \setminus (B \cup C)$. Then $x \in A$ but $x \notin B \cup C$, which means that $x \notin B$ and $x \notin C$, so by definition $x \in A \setminus B$ and $x \in A \setminus C$. This of course means that $x \in (A \setminus B) \cup (A \setminus C)$. Therefore the claim is true.

#### However...

Apparently this doesn't work. My quess is that in ''$\subseteq$'' I made the mistake of assuming $x \notin B \Rightarrow x \notin B \cup C$, which might not be true. Is that the case?

Comment: The 5 is not true. $(A\setminus B)\cup(A\setminus C)=A\setminus(B\cap C)$ is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5) is false. For example if $B$ and $C$ are disjoint subsets of $A$ with $B \cup C=A$ then LHS is $A$ and RHS is empty.

Specific example:  Take $A=\mathbb R$, $B=(-\infty,0)$ and $C=[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Right, but was the implication $x \notin B \Rightarrow x \notin B \cup C$ not true? That was the actual question.

Comment: $x \notin B$ does not tell you that $x \notin B \cup C$.  $x$ could be in $C$. @SeSodesa

Comment: Thank you. That is what I ended up realizing.